# Woocommerce+Wordpress: Remove "Category:" text from title of each category page

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've been scouring the net trying to find the solution for this problem, despite it appearing to be quite simple.

I'm, as the title suggests, trying to remove the "Category:" from the title of each category page, while keeping the actual category text there, e.g. "Category: Footwear" should read "Footwear".

Now I have tried several of the solutions on this site but to no avail. The text still appears as it always has. I am using the Astra theme on WordPress.

I'm currently using the below code, but it doesn't work, hence my asking for help.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'so_remove_category_prefix' );
function so_remove_category_prefix( $title )
{
    if ( is_product_category() ) 
    {
         $title = single_term_title( '', false );
    }
         return $title;
}
```

If anyone has any solutions, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the woocommerce default template in your child theme and change content or title as per your requirement

default template file is located in below folder
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates

You need to create a folder named woocommerce in your theme directory. After creating folder copy the template file folder to woocommerce folder in which you are created in your theme folder